# A three star number puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern

My mother's math department struggled to solve this problem; apparently only one teacher did. I was surprised as I thought it was trivial.

Source: my mother's telegram message

[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree imo it is fairly trivial but being unable to solve a silly puzzle like this with a cursory glance I don’t think makes one a poor mathematician or math teacher…

Anyway

> The rule is: for each star add the top 3 numbers and then take away from that the sum of the bottom 2 numbers added together to generate the number in the middle.

> So for the final star it is (2+9+6)-(4+3)

> Which is 10

My thought process that might help future puzzlers for these kind of number riddles:

> I started off thinking the puzzle probably revolves around using the four mathematical operations but I was using multiplication and division a lot with random number combinations to generate the center number hoping a lucky find might kick in with no avail!

> I tried digit combinations with mathematical operations but that didn’t lead to anything fruitful.

> I then tried grouping the adjacent digits like a strings of 2 and 3 to find common values when operations are applied but again nothing substantial…

> I looked at maybe something meaningful that could arise with opposing sides of the stars but nothing did.

> Finally I thought this puzzle is probably for kids and I thought maybe there is a kind of a top and bottom half kind of relation because it seemed like something you would find in these kinds kiddy puzzles and then limited myself to just addition and subtraction and then the answer hit me.

Comment: Nice one did you google it though?

Comment: Haha  no that would have saved me a lot of time though, I didn’t know why on earth I didn’t think of that!